# Meteor Tracker.autorun behavior

Tags: meteor, meteor-tracker

```
Tracker.autorun(() => {
    const data1 = Data1.find().fetch()
    const data2 = Data2.find().fetch()
})
```

When Data1 changes, the function reruns and data1 is now another array. But what happens with data2? Does it remains exactly the same array (i mean with the same reference)? If it's not, how can I change the behavior so that meteor doesn't call `find()` again if the data doesn't change?

Comment: When a dependency is invalidated in an autorun, the function is re-run. It's a plain JS function, so the way it is structured, it will re-fetch the data in both expressions. For more granular control, you would need to use separate autorun callbacks. What is your use-case?

Comment: @MasterAM Thanks. I am using it with Redux so i need the array to retain the same reference if the data doesn't change in order to avoid unnecessary rerenders. I don't really like the withTracker approach and prefer to have all my application state in one place

Comment: In that case, having an `autorun` per query and dispatching an action might be the way to go. You might make it even more granular using `observeChanges`, if you need, but it will be significantly more complex.